# Android LocationListener onLocationChanged Event Not Firing Consistently

Tags: android, gps, location, locationlistener

I have an activity with a MapView and properly implementing LocationListener, LocationSource as recommended in the code samples.

Code conditionally selects GPS or NETWORK provider depending on which is available, with GPS taking priority.

I'm able to request location updates and the code works well, however the problem is that it is not consistent.

In testing with enabling/disabling GPS & location options and changing mock locations, the onLocationChanged event does not always fire.

The problem happens specifically when using GPS_PROVIDER - GPS icon in notification bar comes up, however no location updates are received.

NETWORK_PROVIDER seems to be more consistent in firing onLocationChanged. But in some cases it also will not fire the event if GPS is enabled on the device. If GPS is disabled on device, with general location enabled, event fires every time.

The only consistent that I've found of getting a reliable location was to call `_map.getMyLocation()` after a small timeout about 1 sec, and a simple retry loop as there is a delay for the map view to initialize.

Is there a workaround for this?

Why is the LocationListener behaving so inconsistently?

Comment: you should be using this http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html and not the old location API

Comment: Thanks, what is the min SDK requirement? Need to have it run on SDK 8 and up.

Comment: have you looks at the android distribution charts lately, only 0.5% devices use 2.2 why are you even supporting it. https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html and no you need 2.3

Comment: I agree with you about 2.3. The support libraries I believe support down to 8 so I picked the lowest. I'm fine with 2.3 and up, is that what it supports?

Comment: yes 2.3 and up is supported

Comment: Awesome, looking into the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: just be warned that the documentation is old and a lot of the stuff has changed in the API. unfortunately they did not update the documentation to show those changes